# TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') funciona as vezes

Tags: java, oracle

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Utilizo o `JDBC` para se conectar com o Oracle. E chamo `rs.getTimestamp(index)` para pegar um campo data.

Quando executo a função `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` o `getTimestamp` as vezes retorna um valor negativo, as vezes retorna o valor correto.

Sei que o `TO_DATE` não está sendo usado corretamente, pois ele deve receber uma string. Mas, mesmo assim, eu gostaria de saber o motivo de o resultado variar.

Obs: essa variação só ocorre no `getTimestamp` do Java. Se eu rodar o `TO_DATE` diretamente no banco, o resultado é sempre o mesmo.

Obs²: Quando o resultado vem negativo, a data formatada retornada pela função é `0014-03-17 00:00:00.0` e quando vem o resultado correto vem como `2017-03-14 00:00:00.0`.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude http://www.guj.com.br/t/formatar-data-no-padrao-dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss/42479

Comment: `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`? Assim, retira-se a hora.

Answer (score 3):

Como você disse, o `TO_DATE()` espera uma string como parâmetro. 
Quando você executa  `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` implicitamente o Oracle converte sua query para `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate), 'DD MONTH YYYY')` e como não foi passado o segundo parâmetro para o `TO_CHAR(sysdate)` ele vai pegar a máscara padrão do seu NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS. 
Dessa forma pode acontecer que algumas datas funcionem com a máscara padrão e outras não.

Comment: Tenho conhecimento disso. Mas a máscara de conversão NLS do oracle é uma só. Eu quero saber o motivo de funcionar AS VEZES. Qual é o padrão pra isso ocorrer? É problema do banco, do driver ou do java?